# Select Record between two dates

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, sql-server-2014, between, qsqlquery

[image: sql query and table result]

I have a table name sale where I have record of different sales now i want to pick record between two specific dates but when i run query in sql i gives null in result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have couple of guesses... First, your `date` column is of type `varchar`.

Secondly, you have your format dates wrong, standard for SQL is `yyyy-MM-dd`, so I recommend using that.

So, first you need to change datatype:

```
alter table sale
alter column [date] date
```

And then filter with appropriate format (but this is only guess):

```
where [date] between 2019-02-09 and 2019-04-09
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the following query

```
SELECT * 
FROM 
TABLE_Name 
WHERE Column Between Date and DateU
```

U meaning Upper date and L mean Lower Date

Answer (score 0):

Try this
`SELECT SUM(SALE.PRICE) AS AMOUNT FROM SALE WHERE SALE.DATE BETWEEN '09-02-2019' AND '09-04-2019';`
 or might be the problem of date format also try this
 `SELECT SUM(SALE.PRICE) AS AMOUNT FROM SALE WHERE SALE.DATE BETWEEN '2019-02-09' AND '2019-04-09;'`

Answer (score 0):

Try using DATEPART,

```
SELECT SUM(price) as 'Amount'
FROM sale 
WHERE (YEAR(date) between YEAR('09-02-2019') AND YEAR('09-04-2019')) AND
(MONTH(date) between MONTH('09-02-2019') AND MONTH('09-04-2019')) AND
(DAY(date) between MONTH('09-02-2019') AND DAY('09-04-2019'))
```

Answer (score 0):

you are getting null since there are no record for  the specified dates. 9-4-2019 and 9-4-2019